# Iissue with formsubmit.co url

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

i'm using formsubmit to send my emails  my problem is when i submits the form google recaptcha page will open with url like https://formsubmit.co/myemail@gmail.com i wanted to change this url to my website url . is that possible???

**below is my form**

```
<form class="app_form_wrapper" action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail@gmail.com" method="POST" >
            <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">
                <div class="form-group apps-pulldown-20">
                    <div class="apps_input">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name"required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group apps-pulldown-20">
                    <div class="apps_input">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email"required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group apps-pulldown-20">
                    <div class="apps_input">
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" minlength="10" maxlength="15"required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="form-group apps-pulldown-20">
                    <div class="apps_input">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" placeholder="Company"required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group apps-pulldown-20">
                    <div class="apps_input">
                        <textarea rows="10" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message"required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_url" value="http://localhost/app/contact">
            <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="http://localhost/app/mailSent.html">
            <input type="text" name="_honey" style="display:none">
            <input type="hidden" name="_template" value="table">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>
                    This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google
                    <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> and
                    <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms">Terms of Service</a> apply.
                </p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg contact_btn">Send</button>
            </div>
    </form>
```

Thanks
Harshith

Answer (score 0):

FormSubmit has gives you 2 different options, you can either skip the ReCaptcha page (It's not recommended but offered.) or you can replace your naked email address with a random string.

**Option 1**

You can use below hidden input field to skip the captcha page:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
```

**Option 2**

> Get a random-like string to replace your naked email address in the
> action attribute of your form. Your email address will remain unknown
> to spam-bots and human visitors.
>
> This random string will send to you when you confirm your email
> address.

Please also refer to their official documentation: https://formsubmit.co/documentation

Answer (score 0):

I deconstructed my email address into a javascript variable so that the email address isn't hard coded into the html. This avoids spam.

```js
  //email
  const email = 'youremail@youremail.com';
  const encodedEmail = encodeURIComponent(email);
  const url = `https://formsubmit.co/${encodedEmail}`;
```

```html
<form 
  target="_blank" 
   action={url} 
   method="POST"
   >
   <input
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Email Address"
                        required
                      />
                       <button type="submit">
                       SUBMIT FORM
                       </button>
</form>
```